# Unit testing parts that use a Value Object that is being created by a Factory

Tags: java, unit-testing, domain-driven-design, factory, value-object

Here is the conundrum,

I have a fairly complex Value Object and I don't want to expose it's internals. It should not be an Entity since there is no need for attaching an identity to it. According to Eric Evans in his DDD Reference book it is Ok to use a Factory in order to create complex Value Objects:

> Shift the responsibility for creating instances of complex objects and aggregates to a
> separate object, which may itself have no responsibility in the domain model but is still
> part of the domain design. Provide an interface that encapsulates all complex assembly and that does not require the client to reference the concrete classes of the objects being instantiated. Create an entire aggregate as a piece, enforcing its invariants. **Create a complex value object as a piece, possibly after assembling the elements with a builder**.

In order to constraint the construction process, the Value Object constructor is package private and the Factory resides in the same package as the Value Object. All other classes that represent the internals of the Value object are package private and reside in the same package. The Value Object is marked as **final** in order to guarantee immutability. This Value Object is being used by Services that reside in a different package.

The question is, how to write unit tests for the Services that depend on this Value Object without actually using the Factory in the unit tests?

The Value Object can't be mocked considering that it has no public constructor and is final. Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the Factory in unit tests?

Comment: @bdsl ideally, I would want my unit test to fail if something is wrong with logic in the unit I am testing, which is the Service in this case. If something is wrong with my Factory it shouldn't cause the Service unit test to fail.

Comment: Thanks. As VoiceOfUnreason suggests in their answer, I think it's probably not worth trying to achieve that. Just assume the Factory is reliable and deal with the failures if they happen - same as you're assuming the VO is reliable. Although may depend how awkward or complicated the factory is.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Just a side note of sorts. Consider also that the package where your value object and its factory reside is a component in its own right, that needs to interact with other parts of the project - namely, other components use the value object and its factory - which means that both of these are a part of the component's API. The subset of tests that covers externally visible behavior of these two is therefore simultaneously a *runnable specification* of this API, and if these fail, it means that the whole app won't work. So anyone changing that package should run that subset of tests first.

Comment: I agree that together they can be viewed as a component of sorts. The problem here is that the API they provide can not be mocked when writing unit test for units that depend on that API, like the Service I mentioned. But as VoiceOfUnreason mentioned, by creating more layers of indirection that can be achieved. Also, I wouldn't like to rely on ordered test execution in any way.

Comment: Sorry, I worded that badly - I didn't mean to suggest that test execution should be order dependent, but that one should have an *option* to run a subset of tests, and that tests that are associated with the public interface of a component should somehow be demarcated. I understand that the problem is mocking (that's why I said my comment was a side note). My other point is that in case you don't want to add extra indirection, then if you have good tests for the factory (which is just a glorified constructor), using the factory... 1/2

Comment: ...in other tests is, while not ideal, not that big of a deal - assuming you can nail down the factory's interface - the stability factor mentioned by VoiceOfUnreason - 'cause changing how the factory is meant to be used will likely make you change those other tests too. Now, if the client-facing structure and/or abstract behavior of the value object itself is unstable, adding an interface is *not* going to help, because the interface itself is going to be unstable and superfluous; in that case, the mitigation is to rethink the design, there's no way around it. 2/2

Comment: @FilipMilovanović oh I see what you mean now. Thanks for clarifying. That "not ideal" part of using a factory was the thing that was bugging me primarily, and I was wondering if there was a way to make it ideal. But hearing your opinion and opinions of others here on this matter convinced me I could, and probably should, live with the "not ideal" for my particular situation. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how to write unit tests for the Services that depend on this Value Object without actually using the Factory in the unit tests?

You add more layers of indirection.

If you have "services that depend on a value object", then you refactor the code so that instead you have "services that depend on an interface implemented by the value object".  Then, in your test, instead of measuring the behavior of your services by passing in references to a "real" value object, you can pass in references to a test double.

For services that also depend on the *factory*, it's the same pattern again; you refactor the service to depend on an interface, and then use test substitutes to produce the test isolation.

---

BUT: before you go down that road, do a back of the envelope estimate to make sure that the benefits you expect to gain by isolating these components offset the costs.

Last time I checked, nobody is handing out prizes for "unit" tests.  If testing a composition of several modules together gets the job done (ie detects mistakes in a time efficient/cost effective way), then that's *fine*, and you probably aren't going to realize additional benefit by redesigning to support solitary (rather than socialable) testing.

One context in which you might care a lot about isolation is when the implementation of the factory or the value object is *unstable*.  If we're getting a lot of false positives in our *service* tests because the expected behaviors of the value object keep changing -- that's bad, and some form of mitigation (perhaps the one described above) will be appropriate.

Comment: yep, makes sense. I was missing the indirection as a potential solution, but I will keep using the factory within tests considering the second part of the answer. Thanks for the insight. It helped a lot.